# Compute the dot product of all combinations of two rows in a matrix

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm super new to programming and I'm trying to compute the dot product of all of the combinations of any tow rows in a N*3 matrix.

For example for N = 5 I have matrix

```
   [0.64363829, 0.21027068, 0.7358777 ],
   [0.39138384, 0.49072791, 0.7784631 ],
   [0.22952251, 0.90537974, 0.35722115],
   [0.40108871, 0.88992243, 0.21717715],
   [0.06710475, 0.84022499, 0.53806962]
```

and I'd like to compute the dot products of all combinations of the rows like: row1*row2, row1*row3, row1*row4, row1*row5, row2*row3 ... row4*row5.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem so I've tried a few things. So far I have

```
for i in range(N-1): 
    for l in range(1, N): 
        dotms = (np.dot(nmag[(i),:], nmag[(i+l),:]))
        print(dotms)
```

where nmag is the 5*3 matrix

the output only has 7 answers, but with 5 rows I'm looking for 10 different combinations

`[0.9279489, 0.6009753, 0.6050964, 0.615819, 0.8122099, 0.7627538, 0.8574529]`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop indices don't quite fit for your task:

```
import numpy as np
nmag = np.array([[0.64363829, 0.21027068, 0.7358777 ],
                 [0.39138384, 0.49072791, 0.7784631 ],
                 [0.22952251, 0.90537974, 0.35722115], 
                 [0.40108871, 0.88992243, 0.21717715],
                 [0.06710475, 0.84022499, 0.53806962]])

for i in range(N-1):  # iterate over all rows but the last
    for j in range(i+1, N):   # start j from i+1 
        dotms = np.dot(nmag[i, :], nmag[j, :])
        print(dotms)
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont't know if I misunderstand what you mean or not, however will `nmag.dot(nmag.T)` get what you want?

```
In [5]: nmag.dot(nmag.T)
Out[5]:
array([[1.        , 0.92794895, 0.60097537, 0.60509647, 0.6158193 ],
       [0.92794895, 0.99999999, 0.81220999, 0.76275381, 0.85745291],
       [0.60097537, 0.81220999, 1.00000001, 0.9753569 , 0.96833458],
       [0.60509647, 0.76275381, 0.9753569 , 1.        , 0.89150645],
       [0.6158193 , 0.85745291, 0.96833458, 0.89150645, 1.        ]])
```

and if you just want to get the dot products of different rows.

```
In [17]: res = nmag.dot(nmag.T)

In [18]: [res[i, j] for i in range(res.shape[0]) for j in range(res.shape[1]) if i<j]
Out[18]:
[0.9279489524047824,
 0.6009753676942861,
 0.6050964675806133,
 0.6158193009466447,
 0.8122099927113468,
 0.7627538110746328,
 0.8574529124107328,
 0.9753568970221529,
 0.9683345820770881,
 0.8915064490330812]
```

Answer (score 0):

To bounce on Woods Chen excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56957749/6630397), one can in addition use [`np.triu()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) or [`np.tril()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) along with their respective function for building indices for a given shape of a triangular matrix: [`np.triu_indices()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) or [`np.tril_indices()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html). This is useful if we want to only extract non-redundant parts (because such dot product matrix is symmetrical by definition).

Here is an example using the upper triangle part of the dot product matrix:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[0.64363829, 0.21027068, 0.7358777 ],
                [0.39138384, 0.49072791, 0.7784631 ],
                [0.22952251, 0.90537974, 0.35722115], 
                [0.40108871, 0.88992243, 0.21717715],
                [0.06710475, 0.84022499, 0.53806962]])

dp = mat.dot(mat.T) # dp := dot_product matrix

dp_unique_vector_indices = np.triu_indices(mat.shape[0]) # assume square matrix
dp_unique_vector_indices_without_diagonal = np.triu_indices(mat.shape[0], 1) # skip the diagonal of ones here

dp_unique_vector = np.triu(dp)[dp_unique_vector_indices]
dp_unique_vector_without_diagonal = np.triu(dp)[dp_unique_vector_indices_without_diagonal]
```

`dp_unique_vector` is as follow:

```
array([1.       , 0.927949 , 0.6009754, 0.6050965, 0.6158193, 1.       ,
       0.81221  , 0.7627538, 0.8574529, 1.       , 0.9753569, 0.9683346,
       1.       , 0.8915064, 1.       ])
```

while `dp_unique_vector_without_diagonal` is:

```
array([0.927949 , 0.6009754, 0.6050965, 0.6158193, 0.81221  , 0.7627538,
       0.8574529, 0.9753569, 0.9683346, 0.8915064])
```

Compared to the full dot product matrix:

```python
array([[1.       , 0.927949 , 0.6009754, 0.6050965, 0.6158193],
       [0.927949 , 1.       , 0.81221  , 0.7627538, 0.8574529],
       [0.6009754, 0.81221  , 1.       , 0.9753569, 0.9683346],
       [0.6050965, 0.7627538, 0.9753569, 1.       , 0.8915064],
       [0.6158193, 0.8574529, 0.9683346, 0.8915064, 1.       ]])
```